# jquery ajax problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

im comparing string to make ajax work here is html page

```
 $("#contact").submit(function(){

       $.ajax({
         url:"contact_ajax.php?action=contact",  data:"name="+$('#name').val()+"&email="+$('#email').val()+"&message="+$('#message').val()+"&lang=<?php echo $_GET['lang']; ?>",
          success: function(html){
         // $("#script").html(html)
         //alert(html)
         switch(html){
           case "name required":
           jQuery('#name').hide()
           break;
         }
         }
       })

})
```

here php page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',true);

 if($_GET["action"]=="contact"){


if(trim($_GET["name"])=="") echo "name required"; else{   if(trim($_GET["name"])!=="")   echo "name filled"; }
```

so if "name required" is echo back to the page this:   jQuery('#name').hide() should happen
but nothing happens??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to alert html string that you get in the success handler. May be its not matching the required condition.

Try this

```
switch($.trim(html)){
           case "name required":
           jQuery('#name').hide()
           break;
         }
```

Comment: Try to use $.trim(html) in the switch statement, switch($.trim(html))

Comment: ok thanks did work but it's funny cause when i alerted the string it looked the same?

Comment: @tada - You cannot make out the spaces in an alert dialog box. Please vote and accept my answer if it helped you thanks.